# I had an interview with a company that I am excited to work for. When do I ask questions about location and salary?

Tags: interviewing, salary, hiring-process, location

I felt very good with my answers and the interview.
I have been invited for a second interview a week from now. However, I never discussed about the location of work and the salary they are offering with the director of the company (first interviewer). I forgot about it. Can I ask the hiring coordinator through mail? Or should I wait for the second interview to clarify these questions?

Comment: "When do I ask questions about location and salary?"  Did you research the company beforehand to see where they were located?  Did the job posting have any salary information at all?

Comment: It would be very unusual for the location not to be mentioned in the job posting. That's a pretty important piece of information. Did you apply for the job without knowing where it would be?

Comment: @SethR There were different locations in the job posting. Before the interview, the hiring coordinator asked me if I had any preference. I mentioned that I am fine with either of the locations but legally I am allowed to work in two of the locations.

Comment: @Sf02 There were different locations in the job posting. Before the interview, the hiring coordinator asked me if I had any preference and the expected salary. I mentioned that I am fine with either of the locations but legally I am allowed to work in two of the locations and I mentioned expected salary in USD (one of the locations).

Comment: So you did discuss salary and location. You told them your expectations and they didn't tell you it wouldn't work, so it will probably be around what you are expecting. I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Yes, if hired, I am supposed to work for the first interviewer. I forgot to ask him.

Comment: @SethR I gave them 5 different locations (3 different countries) and salary expectation based on one of the countries. I just wanted to know which country are they considering the position for and the salary will be based on which country. I hope that clears up my query.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine not to ask about compensation for the first interview provided you filled up your turn with other questions. It is a good idea to ask location and salary right away because these influence what transpires in your next round, and saves a little time. You have nothing to lose, and something to gain.

Comment: So should I ask about the salary and location to the hiring coordinator via email? Because if they are matching up to my expectations, there's no point in going for the second interview. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, correcting for your typo. Why not?